# Ignore datasource filter on a form in AX 2012?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

I have a form that has a menu item which takes us to another form and per base AX filters on the selected record.

I want to create a separate menu item that takes me to the same form, but instead removes the filter on the record.

Any ideas?

Comment: What form are you referring to?

Comment: You will have to be more specific. Your question is to open ended to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about Dynalinks, Opening a second form from the first, and only seeing the records in the second that relate to the currently selected record in the first.

If so Either remove the Datasource property from your new menu item on the first form, or programmaticly clear the dynalink in the second forms datasource's Init() method

Here is a simple example (from AX2009)
http://ckmun.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/cleardynalinks-method/

Comment: Thank you for deciphering my question David. That was exactly what I was looking for.